# Magento 1.9 CMS Page Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, magento, breadcrumbs, magento-1.9

I have "Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages" turned on but the breadcrumbs aren't showing up. It reads "Home / CMS Page".

The way we have the CMS Pages set up is we create the CMS Page and also a category for that page so we can toggle it on/off in the navigation menu. So a URL rewrite is created so that when you click on that category, it takes you to that CMS page.

The hierarchy only exists in categories.

How can I show this hierarchy for the CMS pages?

Comment: So you want breadcrumbs like on this page: https://biosleepconcept.com/why-bio-sleep Sometimes your template (CSS) can be hiding them? Do you have a page we can visit?

Comment: [http://dev.morrisononline.com] Under the POP tab, if you click on any of the pages on the drop down, I want that hierarchy to show when you are on that page.

Comment: I'm confused then because every page I click on shows the hierarchy at the top of the page. Like: Home / Signage and Home / Products. If your want Home / Pop / Signage the only way I know how to do that is with categories. The same way you nest categories for products you will need to do that with these. They'll be empty categories that a URL rewrite sends to the proper CMS pages.

Comment: That's exactly how I have them set up. I created empty categories and did a URL rewrite to point to the corresponding CMS page but it doesn't show that category hierarchy on the CMS page.